# Set an excel chart filter with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a sheet with lots of standard Excel charts (Not Pivot charts!).

I add data every week and want the charts to show data for the last 4 weeks.

Because I have a lot of charts I want to automatically select the filtered weeks with a macro. Dynamic ranges are not feasible, as there are too many charts with 5 data series each.

When I record a macro and activate the filter for a certain week, I get the following code:

```
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(76).IsFiltered = True
```

The problem for me though is that I only know the name of the week I want to see, let's say "2014-32", but I cannot use that name directly:

```
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection("2014-32").IsFiltered = True
```

produces an error. How can I set the filters when I only know the filter name not the index number?

Comment: Iterate the `FullCategoryCollection` and check the item's *value* against the weekname (string, e.g., "2014-32")?

Comment: Could you explain how to do this exactly? I am quite a vba novice, I was thinking something like
    for each fullcategorycollection in activechart.chartgroups(1)
    select case fullcategoryselection.value

    Case week1, week2
    ????.isfiltered = true
    Case else
    ????.isfiltered = false

Comment: it would be more like `For Each cat in ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection`, and then in your Case statements, `cat.IsFiltered = True`.  Try that and see if you can get it to work. (I've never used the `FullCategoryCollection` and I do most of my dev in PowerPoint anymore but I can probably help if you get stuck)