# excel vba unselect a specific value form a chart series

Tags: excel, charts, series, vba

this should be pretty basic for many participants here. Also, this is my first question here so I'm sorry if i make something wrong.

I am trying to unselect a specific value from charts. Unselecting the category from the chart is the problem. Basically, from all the series in that chart. if one of the series name(Value) is iqual "NotThisSeries" then unselect it.

```
Sub exmpl()

Dim MySeries As Variant

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate

For Each MySeries In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection

  Select Case MySeries.XValues

    Case MySeries.Name = "NotThisSeries"

      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(MySeries.Name).IsFiltered = True

    Case Else

  End Select

Next MySeries

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have 2013 for testing, but did you try: `MySeries.IsFiltered = True`  I'm not sure what the `Select Case` is doing there?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply. Yes, i've tried that at the beggining, and it did not work. To clarify, the chart has 9 xvalues names. one of them, if present in the series, should hide. the great problem here seems to be having the variable check each series name, which it doesnt, it only checks one name, and it exits sub.

Comment: What type of chart is it?  Seems like your XValues are categorical, not continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you are using a `Select Case` when you seem to just need a simple `If`.

The corrected code for that is

```
Sub exmpl()

    Dim MySeries As Series
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate

    For Each MySeries In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
      If MySeries.Name = "NotThisSeries" Then
          ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(MySeries.Name).IsFiltered = True
        End If
    Next MySeries

End Sub
```

If you want to use the `Select Case` to handle other names, here is the correct way to do that:

```
Sub exmpl()

    Dim MySeries As Series
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate

    For Each MySeries In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        Select Case MySeries.Name
            Case "NotThisSeries"
              ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(MySeries.Name).IsFiltered = True
        End Select
    Next MySeries

End Sub
```

**Edit**, here is the corresponding code to hide a category instead of a series.

```
Sub exmpl()

    Dim MySeries As Series
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cat As ChartCategory

    For i = 1 To ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection.Count

        Set cat = ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(i)

        If cat.Name = "NotThisSeries" Then
            cat.IsFiltered = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Here is another SO question that helped with the second part.  See comments to the question.  [Set an excel chart filter with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896074/set-an-excel-chart-filter-with-vba)

Comment: Hi Byron, thanks for the reply. your If code should be correct but it has one thing that we need to correct and that is the whole issue here.I've tried your suggestion and it did not work as i expected. To clarify, the chart has 9 xvalues names. one of them, if present in the series, should hide. the great problem here seems to be to check each series name inside the series collection list of names. if you try to run your code, you will get it to check one name and then exit code. Any Suggestions how can we get the code to check all the series names in the x-axis?

Comment: I added the code to handle a category.  I think you can either hide a category or a series but not an individual bar that is specific to a single series and single category.

Comment: Thanks Byron, that works perfectly. I guess i was stuck looking for something too specific and i did not see any related items to my question. Thanks once again for the help.