# Trying to filter a specific ChartCategory.Name through entire workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm super new to VBA and am working on this project that I need some help with. I have this code that is attempting to loop through every chart category in a workbook and filter those that are named "-". However, as I'm new to VBA, I've hit an issue and am stuck. I tried combining two pieces of code, but they don't seem to be mixing. My code is as follows:

```
Sub Remove_Empty_Graph_Categories()
'Credit:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227007/excel-vba-unselect-a-specific-value-form-a-chart-series
   
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim ser As Series
Dim cat As ChartCategory
 
Dim i As Integer
Dim shtName As String

       
Do

'Remove Empty Graph Categories In Each Sheet ------------------------------
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            'For i = 1 To ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection.Count
                'Set cat = ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(i)
            For Each cat In cht.CategoryCollection
                    If cat.Name = "-" Then
                    cat.IsFiltered = True
                End If
            Next
        Next cht
    Next sht
    
    
 Loop
    
    
    
Sheets("Instructions").Activate



End Sub
```

Thank you for all your help!

[image]

Comment: First step, remove the `Do` and `Loop`.

Comment: I thought you need the Do and Loop to cycle through the entire workbook?

Comment: That's what the `For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` is doing.

Comment: So when removing the Do and Loop, the code still runs into error '438' (Object doesn't support this property or method) on the "For Each cat In cht.CategoryCollection" line.

Comment: That suggests that a `ChartObject` doesn't have a `CategoryCollection` property. Try `For Each cat In cht.Chart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection`, untested.

Comment: I implemented the line you advised to, but am met with the same error as before.

Comment: Try `For i = 1 To cht.Chart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection.Count` and then `Set cat = cht.Chart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(i)`. You may need to add a screenshot of a sample chart, that would help to reproduce.

Comment: That move the code along father, now I'm met with _Run-Time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Name' of object 'ChartCategory' failed_. Now the issue lies with the first line of the **IF** statement. Also, I received a notification that I don't have the authorization to post pictures yet. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You can add an imgur link in the comments and someone will edit it into your question.

Comment: I've added an image.